# Right-angled triangle pattern with recursion numbers C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print a right angled triangle with ascending and descending numbers using recursion only.

```
void straightTriangular(int num)
{
    if (num == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    straightTriangular(num - 1);

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        cout << i;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

How can I do this with recursion only without "for" loop?

if the user input number is 4 then
**I want the output to be this:**

```
1
121
12321
1234321
```

**my output using the code I posted:**

```
1
12
123
1234
```

Comment: There is no algorithm that actually requires recursion, you can always implement it using iteration. I wouldn't even say your case is a good example for recursion, even though it can be used to train it. There are much better ones, like traversing a tree, which lend themselves to recursion much more.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I know it's possible to do this with iteration but I want to know how can I implement this with recursion only.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt some would say that no algorithm actually requires iteration and you can always use recursion. And actually a lot of functional programming languages don't have iteration at all. Obviously in C++ this kind of things should be done with iteration, nonetheless getting accustomed to functional thinking is not a bad thing

Comment: Nitzan, your question is "is it possible...?", which is a yes/no question. In any case, a triangle size 4 starts with one size 3 followed by a fourth line, which is where you have your recursion. Note that there are two tasks: Printing a line and printing a triangle. Make sure you write separate functions for each part, it will make things easier.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have:

- a `printTriangleRec` function that goes on printing every line recursively,
- two `printAscendingRec` and `printDescendingRec` functions that print the two halves of each line recursively.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/EhccWYajM)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout

void printAscendingRec(int cur, int top)
{
    std::cout << cur;
    if (cur != top)
    {
        printAscendingRec(cur + 1, top);
    }
}

void printDescendingRec(int cur)
{
    if (cur)
    {
        std::cout << cur;
        printDescendingRec(cur - 1);
    }
}

void printTriangleRec(int cur, int top)
{
    printAscendingRec(1, cur);
    printDescendingRec(cur - 1);
    std::cout << "\n";
    if (cur != top)
    {
        printTriangleRec(cur + 1, top);
    }
}

void printTriangle(int num)
{
    if (num < 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: num < 1\n";
        return;
    }
    printTriangleRec(1, num);
}

int main()
{
    printTriangle(4);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping :)

Comment: Glad for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that a triangle(n) has a triangle(n-1) on top of it.  It has self-similar structure *above* it.

Also notice that a layer looking like `x...n...x` is `x (x+1)...n...(x+1) x`, which has self-similar structure *inside* it.

```
void layer(int x, int n) {
    std::cout << x;
    if (x >= n) return;
    layer(x + 1, n);
    std::cout << x;
}

void triangle(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) return;
    triangle(n - 1);
    layer(1, n);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

If you want to render a pyramid with each layer centered, instead of a right-angled triangle, then what appears above a layer is not just a simple triangle, but an indented triangle.  You must keep track of this indentation.

The `layer` function remains the same, but you first print out some `space` according to the indentation level of the current pyramid.

```
#include <iostream>

void space(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) return;
    std::cout << ' ';
    space(n-1);
}

void layer(int x, int n) {
    std::cout << x;
    if (x >= n) return;
    layer(x + 1, n);
    std::cout << x;
}

void pyramid(int n, int indent) {
    if (n <= 0) return;
    pyramid(n - 1, indent + 1);
    space(indent);
    layer(1, n);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    pyramid(4, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Btw if I would want to use your code and print a Pyramid instead of a triangle how can this be done?

Comment: @Nitzan I have provided an update with the additional information you requested.

Comment: You could have a standard indentation, e.g. centered on screen/console 80 cols wide. Then no additional indentation parameter would be needed (could be deduced from n parameter).

Comment: @Wyck Again, thank you very much for helping :)

Comment: @Wyck Is it possible to not to use `int indent` ? and to keep it as  `void pyramid(int n)` I was looking for a way to do this if possible

Comment: You can provide a default value of `0` for `indent`.  Declare it as `pyramid(int n, int indent = 0)`.  Then you can call `pyramid(4)` as you desire.

Comment: Or since n is decremented in each step, and indent is incremented, indent could be set to indent = MAXINDENT - n at the beginning of the function